# Can I add a delay/wait to a key mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using MacVim on OSX 10.11 El Capitan, which still has some issues with El Captain's new Split Screen feature – namely, MacVim automatically resizes to 191 columns, taking up most of the screen real estate.

To fix this, I have to manually `set columns=95`, which works perfectly except that then, the entire vim window goes black. The easiest way to fix that is `<C-l>` to redraw the screen.

So, I have the following mapping set up in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Leader>ss :set columns=95<CR><C-l>
```

Problem is, the `<C-l>` command seems to come too soon after the screen is resized, so it remains black and I still have to manually redraw the screen myself. Is there any way to delay the execution of the final `<C-l>` command by a few ms or so (or, even fancier, to wait until the screen has been fully resized) so that I can do this all in one fell swoop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the the builtin sleep function (see `:h sleep`).

`:sleep 2<CR>` lets Vim sleep for 2 seconds, `:sleep 200m<CR>` for 200 milliseconds. There is also the "gosleep" command in normal mode, e.g. `2gs`.

Comment: Brilliant! That did it for me. For anyone interested, here's what my mapping looks like now: ``nnoremap <Leader>ss :set columns=95<CR>:sleep 5m<CR><C-l>
``